# Force on a curved surface of a closed Vessel

Tags: fluid-statics

**Question**

In many regions of the United States, home heating is effected by burning propane. A side
view of a typical propane storage tank is sketched in Figure P2.71. Determine the forces
exerted on quadrant DE for the case when the tank is filled to the top (point B). Tank length into the page is 2 m.

[image: Figure 2.71]

**My Approach**

I know that we must consider the volume over the quadrant DE to find the force acting on it. But looking at my fundamentals I remember that this approach is actually taken by drawing an imaginary surface similar to that of the tank and considering the way the hydrostatic forces are distributed over that surface.(refer figure A)

So my problem is when doing this, do I have to consider the force Fv1 ( the force by the quadrant BC on the fluid) in the process of finding the vertical force acting on quadrant DE? It feels like the correct thing to do, however, I'm not quite confident about what I have done.
Would highly appreciate if you could let me know if this approach is correct.

Figure A
[image: Figure A]

Comment: Propane is stored under pressure. You need to know that pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the curved surface of the quadrant into thin horizontal strips of area [each LR(dθ)]. The pressure at each strip depends on the vapor pressure at the top of the tank, and the depth (and density).  Find the horizontal and vertical components of force on a strip. Then, add them separately by integration. The end caps are treated similarly, but experience only horizontal forces.